# Django custom save and update

Tags: django

I have a custom save method for a model.

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show)
    seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat)
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('show', 'seat')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.paid:
            do_something()
```

In the view I would like to update multiple Ticket objects:

```
Ticket.objects.filter(ref='ref').update(paid=True)
```

But, since this won't call the custom save method. The method `do_something()` won't be processed. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution would be:

```
for ticket in Ticket.objects.filter(ref='ref'):
    ticket.paid = True
    ticket.save()
```

If you are doing the `update` for performance reasons you don't want to give up, you could do:

```
new_paid_tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(ref='ref')
new_paid_tickets.update(paid=True)
for ticket in new_paid_tickets:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.paid:
            do_something()
    super(Ticket, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

use this and add the custom code inside self.paid, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once):

> Be aware that the update() method is converted directly to an SQL statement. It is a bulk operation for direct updates. It doesn’t run any save() methods on your models, or emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of calling save()), or honor the auto_now field option. If you want to save every item in a QuerySet and make sure that the save() method is called on each instance, you don’t need any special function to handle that. Just loop over them and call save().

So you need to iterate over queryset and call `save()` method for each element.